# Progress bars go backwards in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have built a small application using AngularJS.

There is a data table using ng-repeat.  The data table is constantly changing with rows being updated, added and removed in realtime via web socket.

Each row has a progress bar, which is a simple div with a percentage css width set by a property from the data.

Here is a snippet from my html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:query | orderBy:sort.column:sort.reverseorder track by $index">
    <td>
        {{job.id}}
    </td>
    <td class="progress">
        <div ng-if="job.status=='running'" class="progress-outer">
            <div class="progress-inner" ng-style="{width: job.progress+'%'}">

            </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is a simplified version of my controller:

```
workmanagerControllers.controller('JobListCtrl', function($scope, workmanagerChannel, Jobs)
{
    /**
     * Property by which the data set is sorted by default
     * @type {string}
     */
    $scope.sort = {column: 'progress', reverseorder: false };

    /**
     * Populate jobs object from Jobs REST service at first load
     * @type {HTMLElement|*|query|query}
     */
    $scope.jobs = Jobs.query();

    /**
     * Bind add job function to workmanager Pusher channel
     */
    workmanagerChannel.bind('addjob', function (data) {
        $scope.jobs.push(data);
    });

    /**
     * Bind update job function to workmanager Pusher channel
     */
    workmanagerChannel.bind('updatejob', function (data) {
        jQuery.each( $scope.jobs, function( index, value ){
            if(value.id == data.id)
            {
                $scope.jobs[index] = data;
                return;
            }
        });
    });

    /**
     * Bind delete job function to workmanager Pusher channel
     */
    workmanagerChannel.bind('deletejob', function (data) {
        jQuery.each( $scope.jobs, function( index, value ){
            if(value.f_job_num == data.f_job_num)
            {
                $scope.jobs.splice(index, 1);
                return;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This works fine until I added CSS transition to the progress bars to make them smoother.  The progress bars now do strange things like go backwards when a row is added or removed.  I know why this is, but not how to fix it.

This is the transition CSS:

```
.progress-inner {
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Say the table starts with 4 rows - let's call them A, B, C and D.  Row B is removed via a signal from web socket.  Then rows C and D (which were in position 3 and 4) move up to fill positions 2 and 3 respectively.  What seems to happen is the progress bar in row 2 transitions from the progress value of B to C.  And the same with the progress bar in row 3 - it animates from the progress value of C to the progress value of D.

I expected Angular to physically remove the second table row, but in actual fact it seems to re-map the data (causing the transition to occur) and then remove the last row of the table.

The same thing happens if a row is added before an existing row.

Does anyone have any ideas how this could be solved?

Comment: When solving code issues, some code might be helpful :)

Comment: No problemo - didn't think it would add much, but I will update the post with some snippets.

Comment: @naxtek We need the code you added when: `It was working fine until I added CSS animation`

Comment: From your description, i'd assume that your css file would be worth a look, too

Comment: Sorry, I mean transition.  Just a standard 1 sec transition on the element progress-inner.

Comment: I've edited it to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself.

It turned out to be this line:

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:query | orderBy:sort.column:sort.reverseorder track by $index">
```

I'm not sure why I added `track by $index`, but removing part fixed the problem and I've noticed no negative effects.